# Fourier coefficients of $1-|t|$ with $t \in [-1,1]$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I'm asked to find the fourier coefficients $c_k$ of the following signal:

[image]

---

What I did:
(For simplicity, let $ a := \pi i k$. And obviously, the period $T=2$)
$$c_k= \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}x(t)e^{-2 \pi i k t/T}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{0}(1+t)e^{-2 \pi i k t/2}dt + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)e^{-2 \pi i k t/2}dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-2 \pi i k t/2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}|t|e^{-2 \pi i k t/2}=$$
$$ 0 + \frac{1}{2}((-\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{(-1)^k}{-a}) + \frac{(-1)^k}{a^2}) + (-\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{(-1)^k}{a}-\frac{(-1)^k}{a^2})) = -\frac{1}{a^2}= -\frac{1}{(\pi i k)^2}$$

(I hope I did no mistake.)
However, my solution says that I should have gotten $$c_k=\frac{2 \sin^2{\pi \frac{k}{2}}}{\pi ^2 k^2}$$

May I ask you what I did wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It looks like you might have dropped a minus sign. The integrals evaluate to $\frac{-2\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)^{2}}{\pi^{2}k^{2}}$.

Comment: @Jam Did you use a software/ program to compute the integral ?

Comment: I did it on paper and checked with Mathematica.

Comment: @Jam Ah okay Thanks a lot. I'm just wondering how I completely failed to evaluate the integral correctly

Comment: I think you might also have made an error after computing the integral since the terms should be zero at even $k$. So, with your $(-1)^k$ form, you would have something like $\frac{1-\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\pi^{2}k^{2}}$. It doesn't matter whether you use $(-1)^k$ or a trigonometric form, like $\cos (\pi k)$ since they're the same thing; it's just personal preference. But see how you get on after fixing the integral's sign. I wouldn't worry about having dropped the minus sign, I've done it a million times. It can help to go slower methodically through the algebra and keep your notation clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\displaystyle c_k=\frac12\int_{-1}^0 (1+t)E\ \mathrm{d}t+\frac12\int_{0}^1 (1-t)E\ \mathrm{d}t$, where $E$ is the exponential term. After collecting similar integrands, this should become $\displaystyle \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 E\ \mathrm{d}t +\frac12 \int_{-1}^1 (\color{red}{-}|t|)E\ \mathrm{d}t$ since $-|t|=\begin{cases}t,&t<0\\-t,&t>0\end{cases}$, so your second integral should be negative.